Geth for Base Chain Node is stuck arround 100 blocks behind current height. How can i fix this?
I am syncing a base chain node as the layer 2 and I have snap node of ethereum mainnet on the same server. Ethereum main node is working fine but the syncing of base chain node is always keep 100 blocks behind the current block height. Also when i attach the geth client it show me 0 block. Attaching the details for reference
Internet speed is arround 30Mbps and i am using SAS HDDs.


Below are the numbers from the eth.syncing


